# Trying to display all microposts from all users regardless if I am following them or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

Just got done going through the rails tutorial and now I am trying to figure out how to search all microposts and as well as show all micropost accross the board while using pagination. I tried some other examples on here but the scope information was older and didn't seem to work anymore.

```
  def index
    @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
    @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @microposts = Micropost.all
  end
```

is in my `microposts_controller`

and in `index.html.erb`:

```
 <% @feed_items %>
```

This is not showing any information.

Any help would be cool. I am new to all of this rails stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show the information you need to do this (using `<%= . . .`):

```
<%= @feed_items %>
```

You actually would want to loop through the `@feed_items` and show each one's information:

```
<% @feed_items.each do |feed_item| %>
    <%= feed_item %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Perfect. It worked. It worked. I feel silly. How would I search the microposts? Like if I wanted to add hashtags like twitter and facebook have?

Comment: Great to hear that it worked for you. Please post another question with your new requirements and provide necessary details so that people can help you quickly.